# Decrypting files with PGP and C#

Tags: c#, pgp, encryption, openpgp

My problem is when the command line runs it doesn't add anything in my decrypt text file. I added text to the decrypt.txt file to see if it writes to it and it does because the text gets deleted.

```
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\";

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
        string sCommandLine = "echo femme toxin sorghum| gpg.exe --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt E:\\entemp.txt > E:\\detemp.txt";
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(sCommandLine);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

Comment: This is superficially related to C#, you are asking for help with pgp but using gpg... and really it's a gpg question so maybe superuser would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

i've been doing a lot of gpg.exe stuff lately...

i think you are redirecting your gpg command standard out to your file...

you may want something more like this

`echo password123|gpg.exe --yes --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt --output c:\file.txt c:\file.gpg`

you could also call gpg.exe directly in your process instead of calling cmd and then passing a command...if you do that though, you'll nix the "echo" stuff and add `--yes ... c:\file.gpg` and so on to an arguments property. then...your first input will be like `gpgProc.standardinput.writeline(password123);`

this method also gives you the ability to get standard error output and process exit codes for gpg.exe directly instead of cmd.exe exit code, etc.

perhaps that will help...